# fstab issue on mounted drives

Tags: linux, mount, hard-disk, raid, mdadm

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and recently installed two new hard drives running a RAID 1 that I set up using mdadm. But when I shut down and unplug the computer, plug back in the power, then turn the computer on, I get a message that I am in emergency mode The only way I can get past the screen is to edit the /etc/fstab file and comment out the drive. Then doing so I have to stop the /md0 then readd the two drives (sdc, sdd) to md0 and then it has to go through the recovery which takes about 8 hours and then I can mount it to a place by using the `sudo mount /dev/md0 /media/extraDrives` If I add the raid UUID to the fstab file with the type linux_raid_member and try to use `sudo mount -a` it says linux_raid_member is not a valid type so I change it to ext4.

Is it possible that I set up the hard drives wrong or what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If possible it is always better to use the UUID of your devices in fstab.

Maybe you take the MD UUID from `mdadm --detail --scan` (which are only related to the MD drivers) but you need to use the filesystem UUID and set it in your fstab
To get the filesystem UUID run:

```
dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep UUID
```

Example fstab entry with UUID

```
UUID=1205-9EE3          /media/extraDrives       ext4     defaults
```

*The filesystem is most likely ext4 but can't tell you. Because you said you already mounted the drive successfully you could mount it again and list all mount points to identify the type: *

```
$ mount
[...]
/dev/sda1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
[...]
```

*(example output where /dev/sda1 is mounted under /boot with vfat)*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I re-assembled the mounted drive /dev/md0. Then ran the `dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep UUID`. It gives back a different UUID than the `mdadm --detail --scan`. Which had given me the MD array UUID which I was using. So I should use the UUID from `dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep UUID` and with what type? `ext4`? Thank you

Comment: Exactly. And yes I would try ext4 for the start. I edited the answer to be more understandable.

Comment: @twcardenas did this solve your problem ? If yes, remember to close it :)

Comment: Hey, I tried this and a variety of other tries and the raid wouldnt mount so I just mounted it as a regular drive. Thank you for your help though